# Unable to validate the 'required' properties in an array of a JSON

Tags: python, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, python-jsonschema

I have a `draft-7`JSON schema in a file like this:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
    "type": "object",
    "required": [
        "tenantid",
        "owningObjectId",
        "owningObject",
        "cudAction",
        "message"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "tenantid": {
            "type": "string",
            "default": ""
        },
        "owningObjectId": {
            "type": "string",
            "default": ""
        },
        "owningObject": {
            "type": "string",
            "default": "",
            "pattern": "^TeamUser$"
        },
        "cudAction": {
            "type": "string",
            "default": "",
            "pattern": "^c$"
        },
        "messageDateTime": {
            "type": "string",
            "default": ""
        },
        "encrypted": {
            "type": "boolean",
            "default": false
        },
        "message": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "required": [
                    "name",
                    "teamcode",
                    "enabled"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "name": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "default": ""
                    },
                    "teamcode": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "default": ""
                    },
                    "org": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "default": ""
                    },
                    "enabled": {
                        "type": "boolean",
                        "default": false,
                    },
                    "version": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "default": ""
                    },
                    "orgDisplay": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "default": ""
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am validating JSON/response with this schema below:

```py
# pip install jsonschema
from jsonschema import Draft7validator
def validate_response(response, schema_file_path: str) -> bool:
    """
    Validate the input message based on the input schema provided.
    :reference http://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/
    :param response: response received as JSON
    :param schema_file_path: The schema file path
    :return validated: returns True if valid response else False
    """
    validated = True
    with open(schema_file_path, "r") as schema_reader:
        schema = json.loads(schema_reader.read())
    errors = Draft7Validator(schema).iter_errors(response)
    for error in errors:
        print(error.message)
        validated = False
    if validated:
        print(f"Valid response")
    return validated
```

However, for a JSON like below `faulty_json_response` where the `message` field value array is empty and none of the `required` properties exists under the `message` field, the validator does not throw any error. What may be the cause?

```
faulty_json_response = {
        "tenantid": "5e3bb57222b49800016b666f",
        "owningObjectId": "5e680018ceb7d600012e4375",
        "owningObject": "TeamUser",
        "cudAction": "c",
        "messageDateTime": "1584460716.01416",
        "encrypted": false,
        "message": [],
    }
```

Please let me know if more details needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `items` keyword applies the subschema value (which includes our required), to each item in the applicable array (`message` in your case).

Given you have no items IN the `message` array, the subschema isn't applied, and so you don't get any validation errors.

If you want to specifiy the array has a minimum number of items, you can do that with the `minItems` keyword...

> The value of this keyword MUST be a non-negative integer.
>
> An array instance is valid against "minItems" if its size is
> greater    than, or equal to, the value of this keyword.
>
> Omitting this keyword has the same behavior as a value of 0.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-validation-01#section-6.4.4

You can see this in action in this live demo https://jsonschema.dev/s/yMM0c

Comment: Excellent, Ben.  Combining this `minItems` with the existing `required` field has enabled me to achieve the desired behaviour. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: do you mind sharing how did you include minItems in your schema?

Comment: It would need to have been added to the value schema of `message`, as a sibling of `type` and `items`. Let me know if that's not enough and I'll make a GitHub Gist.